# How to insert EJS tag inside of apostrophes?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to make a GET request to a certain endpoint by clicking a button that has `onClick=location.href` attribute.
But I can't figure out how to make EJS tag work inside of apostrophes.

```
<button type="button" onclick='location.href="/<%= todoList.title %>"'>delete</button>
```

I want to get this as an outcome:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href="/football">delete</button>
```

Whereas I'm getting,

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href="/">delete</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try**

```
<button type="button" onclick='location.href="/<%- todoList.title %>"'>delete</button>
```

use `<%- %>` rather than `<%= %>` in JS(onclick function)

**Or**

use link whether using button with onclick function

```
<a href="/<%= todoList.title %>">delete</a>

// if you use bootstrap as framework
<a href="/<%= todoList.title %>" class="btn">delete</a>
```